# Discord.py bot - TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Tags: python, discord.py

Just started making a bot and was testing if it would come online.

Command:

```
C:\Users\Allied Gaming\hello> & D:/Games/python.exe "c:/Users/Allied Gaming/hello/bot.py"
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Allied Gaming\hello\bot.py", line 2, in <module>
    client = discord.client()
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
PS C:\Users\Allied Gaming\hello>
```

Here is the code:

```py
import discord
client = discord.client()
```

That's all the code i have so far except for my token.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
client = discord.Client()
```

From the documentation, client should be capitalized.

https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Answer (score 0):

The base code I use when making a bot is:

```
import discord
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()
TOKEN = os.getenv('DISCORD_TOKEN')

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='you-prefix-here')

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('I\'m in.')

bot.run(TOKEN)
```

In bot.py and

```
DISCORD_TOKEN=your-token-here
```

in a new file called .env

Hope i could help :)